# How to remove flickering of main window at the beginning of a video in Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm making the application with JavaFX and Scene Builder. I have a fullscreen video before my appliaction start. SO it is a kind of intro for my appliaction.

A video has the same background as my main stage.

The problem is I have flickering effect at the very beginning when I launch the appliaction. Buttons and text from main window appear during like half of a second and then my video start.

**How can I remove  or hide that effect?**

Please, check this link for more clear understanding of my problem

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlIsh.jpg)

**Main Class:**

```
public class Main extends Application {


public static void main(String[] args) {
launch(args);
}

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

  try {

  FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml/card.fxml"));
  Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();

  Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1600, 600);
  primaryStage.setScene(scene);
  scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
  primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
  primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
  primaryStage.setResizable(true);

  primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("logo-icon.png"));
  primaryStage.show();      


   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

  }

}
```

Controller where I place All buttons and text. I also have a video here:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

@FXML  private AnchorPane mainAnchor, anchorRow,  randomCard, randomCardBack, previewCard, bolt1;
@FXML  private StackPane hBoxCat0;
@FXML  private Button btnPalette, btnFont, btnQuestCards, btnNonQuestCards;
@FXML  private ToggleButton btnPref1, btnPref2, btnPref3, btnPref4, btnPref5, btnPref6, btnPref7, btnPref8;
@FXML  private Label lb_randomCard, lb_randomCardBack, answerID, lb_previewCard, category1, category2, category3, category4, category5, category6, category7, category8;
@FXML  private ToggleGroup group;
@FXML  private JFXColorPicker colorPickerCategory;
@FXML  private Rectangle rectRandom, rectRandomBack;
@FXML  private MediaView media;


private MediaPlayer mp;

private static final String MEDIA_URL = "intro.mp4";

@FXML
 public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

mp = new MediaPlayer(new Media(this.getClass().getResource(MEDIA_URL).toExternalForm()));
media.setMediaPlayer(mp);
media.setSmooth(true);
mp.setAutoPlay(true);

Timeline tm = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(3000), new KeyValue(media.opacityProperty(),  0.0)));
tm.setDelay(Duration.millis(5500));
tm.play();    

addQuestionsToArrayCat1();
addAnswersToArrayCat1();
addSentencesToArray();
matchSentences();   

  }

}
```

Comment: The video takes time to load (asynchronously). You'll need to keep the "background" controls hidden (e.g. `setVisitble(false)` or covered) until the video is playing. Then make them visible which will allow them to "fade in" as the video fades out. See if waiting for the `MediaPlayer` to transition to [`PLAYING`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.Status.html#PLAYING) helps.

Comment: Thank you! @Slaw I got it, I think you should post that comment as an aswer)